# Understanding the string represented data type in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I have a String like **`'12,23,43,erogol,bla,3.4'`** and I want to parse it and see which type of values are in this string. For example if I give that string to function I expect to have a vector like `output=["integer,integer,integer,string,string,double"]` as the return of the function.

How could I do it in matlab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very easily using regular expressions.

```
input = '-12,12,0,erogol,bla,3.4,-3.4';
```

- First replace the strings with 'string'.
- Next catch the doubles
- Finally catch the integers:

Example:

```
  output = regexprep(input, '[a-zA-Z]*', 'string');
  output = regexprep(output, '[-]*[0-9]*[.][0-9]*', 'double');
  output = regexprep(output, '[-]*[0-9]*', 'integer');
```

Output now contains `` `integer,integer,integer,string,string,double,double' ``

Which you can split into a cell array using:

```
varTypes = regexp(output, ',', 'split');
```

Comment: I guess for the string one need to use + other than *

Comment: Yea maybe, for this test case `+` and `*` are giving the same results.  This won't however catch strings that contain numbers. So `string1` will get converted to `stringinteger`.